# Using Varnish as load balancer

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, haproxy, varnish

Varnish already support load balancing HTTP 1.1 and Web Socket requests, e.g. https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/LoadBalancing

Since we already using `Varnish` for caching purpose, are there any benefit if we add `nginx` or `ha proxy` in front of `Varnish` for load balancing, or should we just use Varnish for load balancing?

Seems this approach is quite rare, and why?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve, and why do you want to make your setup more complex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer : I'm a varnish fanboy.

I'm not aware of people putting nginx in front of varnish : they sometimes do the opposite as nginx is supposed to be a lightweight webserver.

Unless I have a good reason not to do so, I would do the load balancing with varnish.

However using varnish for load balancing can be tricky :

- You don't want varnish to be single point of failure so you think about 2 servers at least.
- With active active setup you'll have to deal with cache consistency problem and set url purge in case of update.
- With active passive setup, you'll have to deal with cache stampeding.

Comment: The fact that varnish does not do https, while nginx does, is the reason I put nginx in front of varnish sometimes.